# UDEV Rule for external mouse detection to turn Touchpad On and Off

Tags: mouse, touchpad, bluetooth, udev, synaptics

The following udev rule works partially, it will turn the touchpad off however it will not re-enable the touchpad if the bluetooth mouse is disconnected.

I have noticed that xinput updates if the mouse is added, which picks up the first part of the UDEV rule however xinput *does not* update if that same mouse is disconnected, as in remove the bluetooth mouse from the xinput list. I was thinking that perhaps that is the issue with re-enabling the touchpad but have no idea how to go about it?

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/01-touchpad.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="mouse[0-9]*", ACTION=="add", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/username/.Xauthority", RUN+="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=1"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="mouse[0-9]*", ACTION=="remove", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/username/.Xauthority", RUN+="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0"
```

From 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Disable_touchpad_on_mouse_detection

Comment: The rules seem good, could you try rename the file to `99-touchpad.rules`

Answer (score 1):

I want to add an edit for people desperate with the ALPS touchpad which is recognized in ubuntu 16.04 as a mouse and not as touchpad.

It's enough to modify the script as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh 
# 
# Enables the touchpad if and only if there aren't any external mice connected. 
# 
# Originally from: 
#     https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#System_with_multiple_X_sessions

# This supports also ALPS touchpads.

#Here puts how is named (Run 'xinput list' for the name to put below)
TOUCHPAD="ALP..." 
FOUND=0 

for MOUSE in `find /sys/class/input -name mouse\*` 
do 
    if [ "`cat $MOUSE/device/name`" != "$TOUCHPAD" ] 
    then 
        FOUND=1 
  #Find a Mouse device other than the TouchPad and record the variable.
        break 
    fi 
done 

DISPLAY=:0 
export DISPLAY 
for USER in `w -h | cut -d\  -f1 | sort | uniq` 
do 
    XAUTHORITY=`sudo -Hiu $USER env | grep ^HOME= | cut -d= -f2`/.Xauthority 
    export XAUTHORITY 
    TOUCHPADDEVICE=$(($(xinput list | grep -i "$TOUCHPAD" | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d[ -f1)+0)) 
#Find the Touchpad Id
    if [ $FOUND -eq 1 ]; then
#If another device is founded, disable touchpad
        xinput disable $TOUCHPADDEVICE
    else
#else enable touchpad
        xinput enable $TOUCHPADDEVICE
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

First create the script to turn touchpad on and off.
Know how the touchpad is named:

```
xinput list
```

[image: example]

Then create `NAMEOFSCRIPT.sh` file

```sh
#!/bin/sh 
# 
# Enables the touchpad if and only if there aren't any external mice connected. 
# 
# Originally from: 
#     https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#System_with_multiple_X_sessions 

#Here puts how is named
TOUCHPAD="PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" 
FOUND=0 

for MOUSE in `find /sys/class/input -name mouse\*` 
do 
    if [ "`cat $MOUSE/device/name`" != "$TOUCHPAD" ] 
    then 
        FOUND=1 
  #Find a Mouse device other than the TouchPad and record the variable.
        break 
    fi 
done 

DISPLAY=:0 
export DISPLAY 
for USER in `w -h | cut -d\  -f1 | sort | uniq` 
do 
    XAUTHORITY=`sudo -Hiu $USER env | grep ^HOME= | cut -d= -f2`/.Xauthority 
    export XAUTHORITY 
    TOUCHPADDEVICE=$(($(xinput list | grep -i touchpad | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d[ -f1)+0)) 

#Find the Touchpad Id
    if [ $FOUND -eq 1 ]; then
#If another device is founded, disable touchpad
        xinput disable $TOUCHPADDEVICE
    else
#else enable touchpad
        xinput enable $TOUCHPADDEVICE
    fi
done
```

Don't forget make it executable!

```
chmod +x NAMEOFSCRIPT.sh
```

Then create the rule (require root)

```
gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/01-touchpad_toggle.rules
```

(It can be any name, preferably assign `01` to the beginning)

```udev
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="mouse[0-9]*", ACTION=="add", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/**$USERNAME**/.Xauthority", RUN+="**PATH TO NAMEOFSCRIPT.SH**" 
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="mouse[0-9]*", ACTION=="remove", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/**$USERNAME**/.Xauthority", RUN+="**PATH TO NAMEOFSCRIPT.SH**"
```

If everything goes well, when I connect the USB mouse it disables Touchpad, and when disconnected, activates it.
For those who have problems to be recognized by USB mouse, run `lsusb` disconnected and then `lsusb` connected.

Sources: https://rufflewind.com/2014-06-24/auto-disable-touchpad-linux